# Objectively deleting data from Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I have a basic test database (Oracle XE 11g) with dummy data in it, and I'm trying to benchmark a few things about it. I don't care what happens to the data.

I tried inserting a lot of data, (about 25 GB) but ran into an error, something like:

```
"...maximum file size of autoextend clause out of range"
```

But it says it got to 11 GB, then stopped. 
Okay, no problem, google says I can run:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_DATA_FILES;
```

... then copy the path, and run this command

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/my/path/to/datafile' autoextend on maxsize 30G;
```

So all of that worked, cool. Now I need to get rid of the existing data, which is all contained in ONE table.

So I decide to run:

```
DROP TABLE my_schema.benchmark_table CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
COMMIT;
```

Now, I assume table and all data is gone, but I check it using the first command I listed, and it doesn't appear to have actually deleted the data. Off to Google again, Oracle's documentation says, and I quote:

> Use the DROP TABLE statement to move a table or object table to the recycle bin or to remove the table and all its data from the database entirely.
>
> Caution:
>   Unless you specify the PURGE clause, the DROP TABLE statement does not result in space being released back to the tablespace for use by other objects, and the space continues to count toward the user's space quota.

Oh, so there's a recycle bin, that's understandable, although I thought commit would take care of that. No problem, I'll just follow the documentation by running:

```
PURGE TABLE my_schema.benchmark_table;
```

It says it worked? Well, just in case, let's check, so I run:

```
SELECT * FROM RECYCLEBIN;
SELECT * FROM USER_RECYCLEBIN;
```

0 rows fetched in both cases. "It must've worked!", I said. But now I run:

```
SELECT file_name, bytes, max_bytes FROM DBA_DATA_FILES;
```

...unfortunately it shows 11xxxxxxxxx under the bytes column, which I assume is bytes used, and 32xxxxxxxxx under the maxbytes section. So the allocated disk space is still no released. I'm going to need that 11 GB freed.

I'd rather not drop the entire tablespace, because there are schemas, abstract data types, indexes, etc. that have been configured that I don't want to delete.

What the heck am I missing?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE <tablename> DEALLOCATE UNUSED`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema003.htm#ADMIN11601

Comment: "which I assume is bytes used" - it's bytes occupied on disk, not bytes used by data. No point in trying to free the disk space if you're going to fill it up again for your next test.

Comment: @Mihai - I dropped the Table, table no longer exists, therefore ALTER TABLE will not work

Comment: @Mat - If bytes occupy the disk, but are not used by data, you're saying the next benchmark will overwrite that space?

Comment: Yes. Search for SQL to determine free space in tablespaces, there's tons around.

Comment: you do realize you can't insert 25gb into oracle XE? is that what you're testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dba_data_files` tells you how big your data files are.  In general, that can be very different from the amount of data in your tables.

You have a data file that is ~10 GB in size (based on the `bytes` figure you posted).  Within that data file, you have 0 or more segments, one segment per table (more or less, there are exceptions for things like partitioned tables or clusters or tables with deferred segment creation but I'll ignore that).  Within each segment is one or more extents.  Within each extent are a number of data blocks.  Within each data block is the data for zero or more rows.

Once you dropped the table, there was no longer a segment with the name of the table (nor were there segments with the name of the various indexes on the table).  Assuming you had no other segments in the tablespace and one data file in the tablespace (for simplicity), that would mean that you have a 10 GB data file with 0 bytes assigned to segments.  If you create another table (which creates new segments) in the same tablespace, those segments will use the 10 GB of space already allocated to the data file.  That would mean that you could insert 10 GB into that new table before Oracle had to grow your data file.

You can see the size of the various segments in your tablespace by looking at `dba_segments`

```
SELECT owner, segment_name, bytes
  FROM dba_segments
 WHERE tablespace_name = <<name of tablespace>>;
```

You can see the various extents that are assigned to each segment by looking at `dba_extents`.